# Domain-0 high CPU load

Tags: linux, virtualization, xen

My Xen HVM machine has 4 cores on 2.4 Ghz however `top` gives me a load of 2-3. There are running 20 VM's on it (most of them are idle). The HDD is also almost idle (200 KB/s write and 6 KB/s read).

`xentop` gives me `Domain-0 -----r     223766  121.0    4376576   26.1   no limit       n/a     4   25  6105332  2824789    0        0        0        0    0` (so 121.0 as CPU% usage).

What's the reason of this? None of the VPSs have high CPU usage. It can't be the IO.

Anyone with some more experience know how to pinpoint this problem?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**: You can find the output of top here: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6166898/top.txt
And here's the `xentop` full output: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6166898/xentop.txt

There are some Windows VM's on it, I'm using Xen in conjunction with SolusVM.

Comment: xentop isn't going to shed any light on this.  Include the output of top so that we can see what Dom0 is up to.

Comment: @3dinfluence I've added the top output. As you can see nothing wrong however the load is 2.49.

Comment: Very strange.  I have a quad core box running 7 light duty vm's on Xen.  The Dom0 is showing almost no activity or load in top or xentop.  Does vmstat show anything out of the ordinary like a high number of context switches?

Comment: @3dinfluence not sure what those numbers mean, but here is the output: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6166898/vmstat.txt  Thanks for sharing some of your time ;-)

Comment: That all looks fine to me as well.  Hopefully someone else will have some more ideas for you.

Comment: Can you pastebin the output of `cat /proc/cpuinfo` on the VM host?

Comment: @TomO'Connor here you go: http://pastebin.com/cJG7JaTk

Comment: Bah.  Well, that's one theory out.  I wanted to check that your CPU supports full Virtualisation extensions, which apparently it does.

Comment: @TomO'Connor Yes it does. The load was always fine, but since ~3 days it's having strange load issues. I've already done a reboot and it didn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The high CPU load has been fixed by updating to Xen kernel 3.4.3 (from kernel 3.1.2).

Thanks to those who tried to help me!

Comment: Great you got it fixed :) Thanks for the bounty award.

Answer (score 2):

Your Windows VMs are probably the root cause of your high CPU load.

Open-source Xen doesn't provide drivers for Windows PV (at least not officially... I guess you could try those [Open Source Windows PV drivers for Xen](http://www.jolokianet.net/70Knowledge/Virtualization/Open_Source_Windows_Paravirtualization_Drivers_for_Xen) or take a look at [this](http://plone.lucidsolutions.co.nz/linux/xen/windows/windows-server-2008-r2-xen-hvm-installation-with-gpvpv-drivers) blog post on how to install Windows 2k8 R2 + the GPVPV drivers - the information there could help you). Btw what versions of Windows are you running on your Windows VMs?

One thing you can try though is go into every Windows VM's Device Manager and change the HAL to ACPI Multi and force reboot.

Finally please post the output of `ps fawwux` to see a list of processes and work out what's using the CPU utilization.

PS: If you want to provide Windows VPS with Xen, use XenServer Express (free) or Enterprise ($$) and use the bundled PV drivers.

Comment: I'm using Xen HVM, not PV. However I will try to change HAL to ACPI and see if that works.

Comment: Oh OK, then please try the thing with ACPI Multi and let us know :)

Comment: The ACPI is no longer in Windows 7 it seems. Also, would the only thing to fix this be on the "client" side rather then on the server side to fix this?

Comment: I've saved all the Windows machine on to disk (so they are no longer active and the load goes back to around 1.5 and now it's rising again to 3.5. It seems the load is lower now, however still not stable at all. I'm not sure if it's the Windows now (I don't think so, since they are not even online anymore).

Comment: Could you post the output of ps fawwux ?

Comment: Here's the output: http://pastebin.com/hBz6e4pi

Comment: There's something about all those qemu-dm zombie processes that I don't like.

Comment: In the past I had serious problems with CPU consumption on Windows XP VMs and had to change the HAL. At the time, I re-installed Windows to force a new HAL by changing the acpi and apic flags in the Xen config.

Comment: @BigChief Even when the Windows VM's are in a saved state (thus offline) the CPU is load is still high. :(

Comment: @Devator: Well I guess it's not the HAL then. Do you see this high load when: (1) the Dom0 is freshly booted with no VMs or (2) when you completely destroy the Windows VMs ? Also, the PV drivers are worth a shot as mentioned previously.

Comment: vm128 vm135 vm131 vm132 still show high CPU load even though they're offline. Those zombie processes shouldn't exist. Can you try killing them (probably wont work - so kill their parent processes).

Comment: vm135, vm131 and vm132 are not offline at all. Why would you think so?

Comment: You can kill their parent processes by issuing a `ps -ef | grep defunct | more`. The first column is the PID, and the second one their parent process PID. After killing all the defunct processes, your load should go back to normal.

Comment: Oh sorry, I though you said that the VM's where offline. I must have misunderstood.

Comment: Only the Windows VM's. I'll save all vm's to disk and see what the load does.

Comment: In a howto I read that vnc for Windows guests might interfere with linux vnc guests. This could also be the cause of high CPU utilization. Can you try to disable VNC on all your VMs (turn vnc = 0 on each .cfg file) and reboot the server so that all VMs get restarted? Is this a development or production machine? If it's the latter I understand that you can't just reboot your dom0 all the time :( Sorry bout that but it's just to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: It's production :( However, will VM's which are paused still be interfering? I could shut them down but then as it's production I'd like to be sure if it really makes a difference. I had 2 or 3 Windows machines running without any issues but now the load is too high (3-4 and goes up as high as 9)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this is massively wrong, but given that you've got 4 cores, and the load average is a measure of number of processes waiting for CPU time, perhaps there's actually no problem.

Have a read of [Understanding Load Averages](http://blog.scoutapp.com/articles/2009/07/31/understanding-load-averages),  I suspect that there's not actually any major problem.

You haven't mentioned whether the server or it's VMs are misbehaving, or if it's just that the load average is higher than you'd expect.  If it's just the latter, you might want to review and readjust your expectations.

From the vmstat output, the host looks happy, the IOWait is low, the load average is less than the number of  cores.  You might want to fiddle with CPU affinities, but I'd say that it's probably actually performing OK, from the information you've provided.

Comment: Unfortunately, the load even reaches 7 or 8 which will give connections errors from the control panel (SolusVM). So it's actually misbehaving :(.

Comment: Do you pay SolusVM for support? Could it be that their product is just pap?

Comment: There are are so many people using SolusVM, I doubt is their product but I will keep it in mind obviously. I don't get your latter question though. What do you mean with it?

Comment: Could you possibly run `ps ef` on the vm host, and pastebin that output?

Comment: Here you go: http://pastebin.com/7yZMpVr9

Comment: Er, sorry.. I think i meant `ps auxef` ;)

Comment: Output of `ps auxef`: http://pastebin.com/NrfNJ1mQ